# Batch - How to cat multiple files together without header records

Tags: windows, batch, concatenation

I'm attempting to merge multiple files together with the following command:

`copy test1.txt+test2.txt test3.txt`

This works just fine, however, the files I'm attempting to merge contain header records at the beginning of each one. Is there a command I can use to exclude the first line of a txt file, and only concatenate the rest?

EDIT: End goal is to combine six .txt files containing hundreds of thousands of records into a single file.

Comment: Looks to be an answer for this on a very similar SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939327/merge-many-txt-file-contents-and-skip-first-line-in-batch-command-file

Comment: is there a similar pattern in the headers?   if so sed awk or  perl  could be used to remove them ......for ex.  perl -npe  's/pattern\/""/' -i test3.txt

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Yes, they're all exactly the same.

Comment: i know <type> command can merge. for formatting u can use mby Gawk or Sed for windows, but they are 3rd party software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works well from the command line for most circumstanses

```
(for %F in (test1.txt test2.txt) do @more +1 "%%F") >test3.txt
```

Double up the percents if you use the command within a batch script.

The above has the following limitations

- Each source file must have fewer than 64k lines, else it will hang.
- Any tab characters will be converted into a string of spaces
- I think there is at least one other restriction, but my memory fails me (perhaps null bytes converted to new line??)

---

The following batch script has no limitation other than each line must be less than 8k in length. But it is probably too slow for large files (batch is a lousy tool for text processing):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>test3.txt (
  for %%F in (test1.txt test2.txt) do for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
    'findstr /n "^" "%%F"'
  ) do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

---

You could write a custom JScript or VB script that could do this efficiently.

My [JREPL.BAT hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) can handle this well. It is overkill, but it will efficiently do the job, even with very large files.

JREPL.BAT is a general purpose regular expression text processor, with many options. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The following will work on the command line.

```
>test3.txt (for %F in (test1.txt test2.txt) do @JREPL "^.*" "ln>1?$0:false" /jmatch /f "%F")
```

If used within a batch script, then you must use CALL JREPL, and double the percents:

```
@echo  off
>test3.txt (for %%F in (test1.txt test2.txt) do call JREPL "^.*" "ln>1?$0:false" /jmatch /f "%%F")
```

Comment: This works perfectly for testing. Do you know of a way I could scale this up to use it for hundreds of thousands of lines?

Comment: @Intentional - Not hundreds of thousands of lines in a single source file, no. That would require an entirely different solution

Comment: @Intentional - added two options that can handle large files. I recommend the JREPL solution, as it is ***much*** faster for large files.

Comment: EDIT - fixed a bug with the JREPL solution. (forgot the begin line anchor).

Answer (score 1):

If all the headers are one line then you can use `for file in test*.txt ; do cat $file | sed '1d;$d' ; done  > output.file`

Explanation:

`for variable in pattern` used bash in a for loop.
Easiest way to demonstrate that is `for a in * ; do echo $a; done` which will list all files (and possibly folder) in the current directory.

The output is piped though sed (stream editor) with the command to delete the first line (assumption: Your headers are only one line long).

`> output_file` should be obvious.

I am sure there are much more advanced methods. E.g. using find with -type f to only get files. But in a pinch this is a very simple solution only using bash and sed  and cat (and you explicitly tagged it as bash and asked for things to be conCATtenated).

---

Edit: As pointed out this syntax is windows-like. So the platform might be windows.

In which case take a look at [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600653/delete-first-line-of-text-file) and the answer which contains `FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1" %A IN ('type "input_file.ext"') DO @echo %A>>"output_file.ext"`

They key is in more+1

Comment: I believe this is a Windows batch question, not unix bash.

Comment: Crap. You are right, because that matches the `copy + ` syntax.

Time to figure out the more+1 command and how cmd.exe handled for loops. %% iirc, but it has been ages.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is indeed for Windows Batch. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Hennes Title and Tags was unclear so i did the same mistake.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia Sorry, question edited.